# What's the Time Complexity for 'abcde' * 100?

Tags: python, time-complexity

In Python 3, what's the Time Complexity for

`'abcde' * 100` ? Is it 100 or 500?

In other words, for a string s of length n, concatenating it m times like:

```
new_s = s * m
```

Is the Time Complexity O(mn) or O(m)? Thanks!

Comment: Those are different things. In a module, CPython is free to optimize the first as a single string of a hundred abcdes, while in the second it can't.

Comment: It's O(mn). Copying a string of length n is O(n). Doing it m times multiplies that by m.

Comment: Asking about time complexity only makes sense when you're talking about variable data. Literals can be processed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation such as

```
new_s = s + s + s + s + s . . .
```

would be O(m^2 * len(s)).  However one hopes that the Python internals are clever and can use the O(m * len(s)) algorithm:  Create a buffer of the right length, fill it repeatedly with `s`, and then create a single result string from the buffer.

Comment: Why m^2? Are you assuming it's going to first compute `t1=s+s`, then `t2=t1+s`, etc.?

Comment: I am  sure that the Python developers did not implement the naive implementation. However if some wrote their own implementation and did it naively, they’d get quadratic blowup, precisely for the reason you indicate.

Comment: IMHO it's even worse than naive, it's incredibly stupid. It would be like implementing numeric multiplication using repeated addition.

Comment: Yet I could point to you dozens of examples where people create a string by starging with `result = ""`, and then repeatedly writing `result += .....` to generate the complete string.  Same badness.  (Better to put the string fragments into a list, and then `join` them.)

Comment: I believe that CPython has an optimization that makes that not as bad as it seems. If there's only one reference to the string, it concatenates in place if possible rather than making a copy. Note that these types of optimizations are only possible inside the interpreter, not in Python code, since strings are immutable to the latter.